# Dynamic element Id to setId(int) - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I saw the syntax definition of `setId(int)` and `findViewByID(int)`.

But how we use `findViewById(R.id.row1)`

I tried using this:

`Object1.setId(Integer.parseInt("repeat"));`

It showed no error but dint run too.

What is wrong? If `setId(int)` takes `int` and and passing `integer` to it, then what is the error. `When I commented the statement the program runs.`

and if `findViewById(int)` accepts integers then is `R.id.object_id` is an integer?
if yes, how is it mapped with the `findViewById()`?
if No, then how to use `findViewById` and `setId`.

Comment: You are parsing a string value to integer. It will give you error NumberFormatException. You might have been using a try catch statement and there an id was not assigned. Now you are accessing the element using findview by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to set your object id yourself , findViewById make access to your R class that contains pointers to your XML items id.

when you define an id in your Xml Layout file like

```
android:id="@+id/txtyourId"
```

in compile time compiler create a reference to your XML Item layout in R class that you can access it from your java code by findViewById

```
View YourItem = (View)this.findViewById(R.id.txtyourId);
```

Comment: Well Arash I got you. That means, R.id.Object is actually a `pointer` to the id. so it is `integer`. but how to use `setId()` then? and is there any idea by which I can remember the names of the Ids I set for my views.?

Comment: setId is for setting an ID of a view that is already exist so that you can use findViewById later to find it again.you can use it like yourview.setId(i) which i is an integer value , but you have to remember it yourself that your existed view have this id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setId(int)` only for objects extending View class.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your Ids as resources and then use setId() of the view to set it.